# How to Collect dijit/form/combobox Selected Values in Repeat Control

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-ssjs

An XPage is used to display the number of points a person has collected, and the number of points remaining (see below).

I have a repeat control which gets a collection of documents meeting a specific criteria.  The last column in the control contains 5 digit/form/comboboxes, which are displayed or hidden, according to the number of fields on each document that contain data.

The layout contains gift cards worth a certain amount of points, and the person can select how many of each gift card they want. eg.
Company   Available in Values of   Points Required     Quantity Requested

The Quantity Requested column contains the digit/form/comboboxes.  As the person selects values in the checkbox, I want the number of points remaining to be recalculated.

The onChange event of the digit/form/comboboxes calls a function in an Output Script which calls an RPC, which in turn calls an SSJS function.  The SSJS function cycles through the documents displayed in the repeat control, gathering the points required information.  I then wanted it to also grab the Quantity Requested.  I understand from a previous posting that because of the way the digit/form/combox is rendered, I can only get the value using CSJS with dijit.byId and perhaps putting the value in a hidden field and retrieving it from there.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how I will do this when the repeat control will make it possible for there to be many combobox1 and combobox2, etc.

The XPage is not bound to a form, because all the items are just calculated on the fly and then discarded.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  If anyone wants the code, let me know and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON RPC service can't interact with any changes made in the browser, see https://www.intec.co.uk/json-rpc-service-component-tree-manipulation-openlog/. This could be the cause of your problems.

You may be able to get around it by triggering a partial refresh (POST) before calling the JSON RPC. In theory that might work, because the component tree (server-side map of the XPage) would get updated by the partialRefreshPost and the updates picked up by the JSON RPC. It's possible though that the Restore View picks up a version of the XPage other than the one for the browser, I don't know. I've never investigated that.

Comment: I didn't understand previously that the JSON RPC service can't interact with changes made in the browser.  I tried the partialRefreshPost, but that doesn't allow me to get at the value.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Before the partilRefreshPost try setting a submitted value XSP.submittedValue, its a key value pair, then from server side access the submitted value.. since it is a string, you can send more than one value if you stored it as json, then do a fromJson server side to get more key value pairs.

Comment: I'm trying to do that type of thing, but from what I'm understanding because it's inside of a repeat control and I'm trying to get the values from outside the repeat control, I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with server java script, I have been doing it the managed bean way with ActionListeners.  If you have the data in the UI, then can you avoid server side processing and do it client side?

You can also use the DOM XSP Object like XSP.setSubmittedValue to have a key value pair sent with your post request to the server side, you can only have one... it can be JSON or any other value you set it to from the client side javascript.